# Parse complex JSON: multiple loops vs. classes

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have a Json of type :

```
{
"JobProcessors": [
{
  "JobName": "ArchivalJob",
  "IsEnabled": true,
  "Batching": {
    "BatchSize": 0,
    "DegreeOfParallelism": -1
  },
  "Settings": {
    "ArchivalJobCollectionPageSize": 50
  }
},
{
  "JobName": "AuditLogJob",
  "IsEnabled": false,
  "Batching": {
    "BatchSize": 10,
    "DegreeOfParallelism": -1
  },
  "Settings": {}
} 
],  
"ScheduledJobs": [
{
  "JobName": "RemoteStartClientCommandJob",
  "PrimaryAction": {
    "ConnectionString": "#JobProcessorsIntegrationSBConnectionStringValue#",
     "Settings": {
      "LeadTimeInSeconds": "600",
      "MaxSrsJobCount": 25
    }
  },
  "ErrorAction": {
    "ConnectionString": "#PairedJobProcessorIntegrationSBConnectionStringValue#",
    "EntityPath": "remotestartqueue",
    "Settings": {
      "LeadTimeInSeconds": "600",
      "MaxSrsJobCount": 25
    }
  }
}
]  
}
```

I want to check the "**IsEnabled**" property for all "**JobName**" for which come under "**JobProcessors**" category.
In C# what i Have used till now is :

```
dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.GetString(1));
foreach (var item in parsedJson)
{
    foreach (var smallitem in item)
    {
        foreach (var tag in smallitem)
        {
            if(tag.IsEnabled.toString()=="true"){
                Console.WriteLine("true");
            }                                 
        }
    }

}
```

This is giving me correct result except the fact that it also iterates for "**ScheduledJobs**" . But the main issue is :

---

> Is this the right or most efficient way to do this ? If possible suggest some better method  .

One that i know of is using classes , but i may not know the json structure beforehand. Also the json is very huge so making classes can be cumbersome !!

Comment: Why are you parsing into `dynamic`? Better create a strongly-typed object  to represent your structure

Comment: Switch the foreach with a for loop. The for loop is always faster then a for each loop

Comment: @haim770 I may not know the structure of class beforehand .

Comment: @Florian Neiss Actually i dont know the count of elements in the array.

Comment: Another workaround is to write a if under foreach (var smallitem in item) to check if the smallitem is "JobProcessors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are already doing `JObject.Parse(jsonstring);` to parse your JSON string, you can use [`SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) with a [JSONPath query](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to find all "JobName" objects under "JobProcessors":

```
// I want to check the "IsEnabled" property for all "JobName" for which come under "JobProcessors" 
foreach (var job in root.SelectTokens("..JobProcessors[?(@.JobName)]"))
{
    var isEnabled = (bool?)job["IsEnabled"];
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Job {0}: IsEnabled={1}", job["JobName"], isEnabled));
}
```

Notes:

- `..` is the *recursive descent* operator: it recursively descends the `JToken` hierarchy returning each item, subsequently to be matched against the remaining parts of the query string.
- `JobProcessors` returns values of properties of that name.
- `[?(@.JobName)]` returns array items (of `JobProcessors` in this case) that are objects with a `JobName` property.
- `(bool?)` casts the value of "IsEnabled" to a boolean or null if missing.

And the output of this is:

> ```
> Job ArchivalJob: IsEnabled=True
> Job AuditLogJob: IsEnabled=False
> ```

Comment: Thanks specially for this `[?(@.JobName)]` .

Answer (score 1):

As in your code snippet we are using two foreach it may take time for large object. So we can do the same thing in a single foreach or if you have some specific node to fetch or search we can use linq, and for this first we need to convert our json object into c# object. For converting Json object to C# you can use this site "http://json2csharp.com/" then we can Deserialize Json object into c#.

It will be something like this

```
string jsonString = "your Json Object as string";
        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
        foreach (JobProcessor obj in jsonObject.JobProcessors)
        {
            string JobName = obj.JobName;
            bool value=obj.IsEnabled;
        }
```

And I also converted given Json in c# object if the Json object is same you can directly use these classes.

```
    public class Batching
    {
        public int BatchSize { get; set; }
        public int DegreeOfParallelism { get; set; }
    }

    public class Settings
    {
        public int ArchivalJobCollectionPageSize { get; set; }
    }

    public class JobProcessor
    {
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
        public Batching Batching { get; set; }
        public Settings Settings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Settings2
    {
        public string LeadTimeInSeconds { get; set; }
        public int MaxSrsJobCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class PrimaryAction
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public Settings2 Settings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Settings3
    {
        public string LeadTimeInSeconds { get; set; }
        public int MaxSrsJobCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class ErrorAction
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string EntityPath { get; set; }
        public Settings3 Settings { get; set; }
    }

    public class ScheduledJob
    {
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public PrimaryAction PrimaryAction { get; set; }
        public ErrorAction ErrorAction { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<JobProcessor> JobProcessors { get; set; }
        public List<ScheduledJob> ScheduledJobs { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope this will help.
Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for this approach , but i did not want to use classes !